How to assign new custom PHP template file (page template) in twentytwentyfour theme of WordPress version 6
Earlier we do below process but now it's not working. not showing the template name in page add/edit  sidebar . I found new steps from admin Appearance->editor but how to edit the file to add our custom php code
to define custom php file for a page

create a php file inside current theme folder (wp-content/themes/)
ex: register.php

put below comment

/*
Template Name: Register Page
*/
?>

open page add/edit from admin panel

select from right side 'Template'


tried above steps, I found new steps from admin appearance->editor but how to edit the file to add our custom php code

Maybe you should try something like this https://wp-cat.net/guides/how-to-create-page-templates-in-wordpress/, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

I already did these steps. It was working in other theme but not current twentyfourteen theme
